# In Jagged Array how to add new element at top i.e at first position & remove last element

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I've got a jagged array,

```
    int[][] array = new int[][] {
        new int[] { 120, 120 },
        new int[] { 135, 120 },
        new int[] { 150, 120 },
        new int[] { 165, 120 },
        new int[] { 180, 120 }
    };
```

I'd like to add new element in it **at the top/beginning ** like:

```
new int[] { 105, 120 },
```

And also, how to remove last element from it? 
 Is there a way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: As it's written, `Array.Copy`. You might want to look at a `List<int[]>` or maybe a `Queue<int[]>` though?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
Array.Copy(array, 0, array, 1, array.Length - 1);
```

That will leave your array looking like:

```
int[][] array = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 120, 120 },
    new int[] { 120, 120 }
    new int[] { 135, 120 },
    new int[] { 150, 120 },
    new int[] { 165, 120 },
};
```

That is, we've duplicated the first element, and overwritten the last. We can then assign the first element:

```
array[0] = new int[] { 105, 120 };
```

---

You might prefer to use a [`List<int[]>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>()
{
    new int[] { 120, 120 },
    new int[] { 135, 120 },
    new int[] { 150, 120 },
    new int[] { 165, 120 },
    new int[] { 180, 120 }
};
```

Then you can insert a new element at the beginning with:

```
list.Insert(0, new int[] { 105, 120 });
```

And remove the last element with:

```
list.RemoveAt(list.Length - 1);
```

A [`Queue<int[]>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8) might be better still, as adding new items to the front will be cheaper.